# EXC_BAD_ACCESS: too much memory allocated?

Tags: c, memory-management, exc-bad-access

I noticed some troubles programming in C within Xcode.
If I try to allocate these three arrays with the dimensions defined below :

```
#define MAX_NUM_VALID 12000
#define ALT_MAX       200000

{
...
double            l_adYMLinkedData[MAX_NUM_STAR_VALID + ALT_MAX][1];
double            l_adZMLinkedData[MAX_NUM_STAR_VALID + ALT_MAX][1];
double            l_adMLinkedData[MAX_NUM_STAR_VALID + ALT_MAX][1];
...
}
```

Xcode returns me an error on runtime saying :

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address:.....)
```

and i can't figure out why. If I limit those dimensions (i.e. 100 and 100), all goes fine.

Any idea?

Comment: What architecture?  i386, x86_64, arm?

Answer (score 0):

That's an awful lot of stuff to be trying to put on a stack (which tends to be a relatively limited resource).

You may want to try doing dynamic allocation such as with `malloc`:

```
double *l_adYMLinkedData = malloc ((MAX_NUM_STAR_VALID+ALT_MAX)*sizeof(double));
// check and use it
free (l_adYMLinkedData);
```

That effectively gives you the same thing. There are subtle differences to do with pointer/array differences such as `sizeof` but they generally won't come into play if all you're doing is indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Stack space is usually limited (4 MB by default in case of Visual Studio). Each of the array takes nearly 1.6 MB and the stack is running out of the space as it tries to allocate further.

Allocate them on heap instead and free them later to avoid memory leaks.